# Call to a member function fails() on array error when using laravel Request classses

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

I'm using a custom request class for laravel form validations.

This is my request class

```
class ContactUsRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'lname' => 'required'
        ];
    }

   /**
   * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
   *
   * @return array
   */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'lname.required' => 'please enter the last name'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is where I call it,

```
public function send(ContactUsRequest $request) {
        $validator = $request->validated();

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/contactus')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
        } else {
            ContactUs::create($request->all());

            return redirect('/contactus');
        }
    }
```

But when I input correct values I get this,

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function fails() on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because request object automatically do that for you and you don't need to redirect back manually and `$validator` variable contains `validated inputs` so in your case you don't need to do anything and you can remove `if` and redirect safely

```php
public function send(ContactUsRequest $request) {
            ContactUs::create($request->validated());

            return redirect('/contactus');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using form request classes**

If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated **automatically** to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.

In order to capture validation failure you may use the **Validator** facade

E.g

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
//...

public function send(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'lname' => 'required'
            // ...
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/contactus')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
        }

        ContactUs::create($request->all());

        return redirect('/contactus');
}
```

[Form Request Validation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation)

[Manually Creating Validators Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators)

And we can keep **ContactUsRequest** like this.

```
public function send(ContactUsRequest $request) {
        $validator = $request->validated();

        ContactUs::create($request->all());

        return redirect('/contactus');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @foued-moussi. I added a little code and hope it's correct :)

Comment: Need to use ContactUsRequest class alsooo :)

Comment: in cas of injecting `ContactUsRequest $request`in your `send` method the `Validator::make()`will be ignored in case of failure.

Comment: Think we doesn't need t since that part will be handled with custom request class. Can I add custom request class also to your code so I can accept ;)

Comment: I rejected your suggest edit  by mistake, could you redo it ?